# How can 2 divs have 1 border

Tags: html, css

Imagine 4 boxes side by side (divs). These are a menu and when one box is selected its border is red and all the other divs borders are black. The problem I have is, is there an easy way to make it so the neighbouring divs to the selected one don't have a black border on the side that touches the selected div. This is because then you would have a selected div with red borders have a second border of a black line which I don't want.

How can you make 2 divs act as if they have a single border?

I am trying to get what I have here perfected.

http://jsfiddle.net/hCK3D/1/

At the moment the white vertical borders interrupt the horizontal grey. This should not be the case, but I do no know how to change that.

Comment: By using the individual border properties such as `border-right`, `border-top` you can gain more control over your borders.  Any chance you could provide an image showing what you currently have vs what you want?

Comment: I shall make a mock up yes. I understand that. But the issue I am having is I want 2 divs side by side to act as if they have a single border. So if the box to the right of an unselected div is selected it should match that border

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the adjacent selector (`+`) in CSS to make this happen. Check it out, four items:

```
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

Here's your CSS:

```
​.item {
    float:left;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
    border-right-width: 0;
}

.item:last-child {
    border-right-width: 1px;
}

.item:hover {
    border: 1px #f00 solid;
}

.item:hover + .item {
    border-left-width: 0;
}
```

​`.item` just sets up each item normally. It makes the right `border` 0.

`.item:last-child` makes it so that the last one has a borer on the right, since it's the last one and won't have a div next to it to simulate a border.

`.item:hover` makes the hovered item have a red border, and it's all 4 sizes

`.item:hover +.item` grabs the next item in the list and gets rid of its left border since the item just to the left of it now has a red border there.

You can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/hCK3D/

**Edit:** This one should do the trick! http://jsfiddle.net/hCK3D/7/

Comment: This is more what I am trying to achieve. You have nearly hit the nail on the head. The final thing I cannot figure out is how do you make the border at the top and bottom continuous. As you can see at the moment the white vertical lines cut into the horizontal

Comment: by setting and unsetting borders on different sides of an element you will get differing results across browsers *(especially with regard to trying to get a consistent line or avoiding singular missed pixels on corners)*

Comment: Thank you. I tried a similar approach. Although when one is hovered the lower border of that box needs to be the same colour as the hover inside colour. I do not think this is possible though. To be fair you answered the original question perfectly so I shall be accepting your answer

Answer (score 5):

By using a combination of negative margins *(the same dimension as your border)* and a singular z-index for the selected div you can achieve the layout you are looking for.

[image: image of divs with "shared" border]

```
<style>
   .box { 
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     float: left;
     border: 5px solid black;
     margin-left: -5px;
   }

   .selected {
     position: relative;
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     border: 5px solid red;
     z-index: 20;
   }
</style>

<div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box selected"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

The above method should be reliable in all mainstream browsers from IE7 upwards... I should imagine it should work for IE6 too but I don't have it to hand to test.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the simplest way to solve your problem is to set negative margins to active div. You code may look like this

```
# HTML
​<div class='menu'>
    <div class='item'>
        Item 1
    </div>
    <div class='item active'>
        Item 2
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
        Item 3
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
        Item 4
    </div>
</div>​

# CSS
.menu {
    position: relative;
}

.menu .item {
    display: inline;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}

.menu .item.active {
    border: 1px solid red;
    z-index: 2;
    margin: 0 -1px;
}
```

Using divs for your purpose is not looks html semantic to me. I think it will be better to use list for navigation.

PS Here is this code in action – http://jsfiddle.net/r8XRP/
    ​

Answer (score 0):

try this one

http://jsfiddle.net/D74mj/

i hope that's the result you requried